# Url parameter not mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following method in my BlogController:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("blog/search/{searchTag:string}")]
public ActionResult Search(string searchTag) {
    // Doing some search
}
```

I want my url to be for example `blog/search/programming` and this should get me to a page showing only the posts that are tagged with `programming`

I also have the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "BlogSearchRoute",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{searchTag}",
    defaults: new { 
         controller = "Blog", 
         action = "Search" 
    }
);
```

Unfortunately my parameter doesn't map correctly and it is always `null`.

**UPDATE**
Additional information: here is my `RouteConfig` class:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
            routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("elmah.axd");              

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "BlogSearchRoute",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{searchTag}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Search", searchTag = UrlParameter.Optional });

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "BlogRoute",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Post", title = UrlParameter.Optional});

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Less precise routes should normally be last. `BlogSearchRoute` is never used when it is after `Default` route.

Comment: Side notes: search text generally does not work as part of "path" segment of URI due to restrictions on characters allowed there; consider to specify explicit urls explicitly to minimize number of conflicts in the routing table: `url: "blog/search/{searchTag}"`. Not directly related to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your custom route, define your `searchTag` as optional using:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "BlogSearchRoute",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{searchTag}",
    defaults: new { 
         controller = "Blog", 
         action = "Search",
         searchTag = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

**UPDATE**

You should define your `Default` route at the bottom under all your custom routes.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem... parameter is still `null`.

Comment: And what if you remove the attribute `[Route("blog/search/{searchTag:string}")]` ? Because now you define the routes in your routings and as an attribute in your controller

Comment: Still doesn't work. See the update, maybe that would help.

Comment: Can you add your entire routeconfig.cs content?

Comment: You have to place your default route at the bottom, now it will always use this route instead of your other custom routes

Comment: After doing so when I run the app I get an error: `An error occurred while processing your request.`. Also if I try to debug the method when I run I am instantly redirected to it while the url is simply `localhost:xxxxx` and so the parameter still doesn't map.

Comment: Maybe `BlogSearchRoute` is the same as the `Default` route?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by removing `BlogSearchRoute`, the `[Route()]` attribute from my method and renaming `searchTag` to `id`

Answer (score 0):

Your route parameter {searchTag:string} has an incorrect constraint type. The ":string" constraint type does not exist and you should either remove the constraint type or take one of the valid ones that can be found in [route constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#route-constraints) documentation.